# Div Error, not staying inline and margin-top not taking effect?

Tags: html, css, layout, inline

I am wanting to make my website have a similar layout to this one here: http://www.mathewporter.co.uk/ but none of my div's are lining up the right way. I have tried using  but that didnt work out right. As you can see on the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vf4Wu/1/ using the css:

```
 div.sidebar{
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-left: 150px;
 display: inline;
 }

 div.content{
 display: inline;
 }

 div.content h2{
 display: inline;
 }
```

Thanks, Im not sure if im asking this right or not. But what should I be using if not divs?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Inline items cannot accept top/bottom margin and padding.

Comment: Okay that works, but it messes up again when I change it to this: http://jsfiddle.net/vf4Wu/3/

Comment: Without knowing what your desired result looks like, I really have no idea what "messes up" means.

Answer (score 0):

Use float for each contanier or display: inline-block

Comment: Okay that works, but it messes up again when I change it to this: http://jsfiddle.net/vf4Wu/3/

Comment: inline-block allows you to set margin rest tags will display inline if you want to use a div display on full width you should use 
"display: block"... Its all up to your requirement